# i just running the croeseid v0.8.1 testnet node(CRO),the node runs upto blockheight = 116426 then it shows the following below

Tags: cryptocurrency

error during handshake: error on replay: wrong Block.Header.AppHash. Expected A3E55D61FD6A1D2B9B33C2EA938EFB7B7D097F604EB729324429DC90E10C371C, got ED6812F726581714F9659496D29071A5D8440B9F8A8D0FA0CF9BF6396069DC65
and i tried v0.9.1 also but i got same error,please give solution for this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by some bug and can happen at random. Try to upgrade your node's binary.

Try the following workarounds:

- Try upgrading your node's binary.
- Run with `--log_level trace --trace` for additional details.
- Remove the data and try to re-sync again. Possibly it won't happen on the 2nd run.
- [Disable appHash checks when on block apply](https://github.com/binance-chain/node-binary/issues/87#issuecomment-582043991) in `config.toml` file (`with_app_stat=false`).
- As the last resort, do the [unsafe reset of all data](https://github.com/maticnetwork/heimdall/issues/696#issuecomment-936275676) (ensure the backup of all configuration files and your keys).
- Report a bug at project's GitHub page.

Read more about the problem at https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/issues/10281.